# Why is "npm install" not failing when I've indicated a higher version of NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

I would like to enforce exact versions of NodeJS and NPM in my NodeJS project. This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "nodesandbox",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "less": "*"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.25"
  }
}
```

When I run `nvm ls` I get this output:

```
    v0.2.6
    v0.7.12
    v0.9.6
  v0.10.12
  v0.10.15
  v0.10.21
current:    v0.10.24
```

When I run `npm install` it works fine, but I would like it to fail. I have followed instructions from this link [1], which is why I think setting the node version in the engines object should work but sadly it is not working.

[1] http://blog.nodejitsu.com/package-dependencies-done-right/#node-dependency-in-apps

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the `engine` dependencies are only checked when the package is taken from another location:

```
[timwolla@/tmp/test2]npm install ../test
npm WARN engine nodesandbox@0.0.1: wanted: {"node":"0.10.30"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.26","npm":"1.4.3"})
```

If `engineStrict` is set to true:

```
[timwolla@/tmp/test2]npm install ../test
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: nodesandbox@0.0.1
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":"0.10.30"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"1.4.3","node":"v0.10.26"}
```

---

If you read [the manual](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-install.html) carefully it may become clear why (I'm not 100% sure about this actually):

Compare

> `npm install` (in package directory, no arguments):
>
> Install the dependencies in the local node_modules folder.

with

> `npm install <folder>`:
>
> Install a package that is sitting in a folder on the filesystem.

The first states to install the *dependencies*, while the second installs the *package*.

Comment: I suspected as much, but was hoping otherwise. Any ideas how can I enforce the version in my own project?

Comment: @190290000RubleMan Well, you *know* about your environment, I think this is a non issue. Otherwise: Use a directory (or repository) and install from there. `npm install` without anything else is imo only relevant for development.

Comment: Yea, perhaps I'm belaboring the point. The reality is that we have multiple developers on the same project, so it'd be nice to have a way to enforce that we're all using the same version of node.

Comment: @190290000RubleMan node should be compatible for every version with the same number in the middle, I don't think you'll issues because of different node version, as long they are not from the stone age. I myself even upgraded from 0.8.x in small steps up to 0.10.26 without a single problem.

Comment: @190290000RubleMan Very good question.  I am in the same position you are.  I would like to enforce a specific version of Node because someone else's package is not compatible with the latest version of Node and breaks my deps

Comment: What a quirk! Thank you - I believe this will be very confusing now that people start using io.js and node, and switching between them. Important answer!